# In Python 3, how do I print multiple expressions on the same line?

Tags: python

I am a beginner.

How do I print multiple expressions in Python 3 on the same line.

Here is some simple code I wrote for a class exercise in my beginner class:

```
temp = int (input ("What is the outside temperature? "))
if temp < 70:
  print ("Wear a jacket ")
else:
  print ("No jacket is necessary ")
print ("when you go outside.")
```

If I input 50 degrees, the output says:

```
"Wear a jacket
when you go outside."
```

whereas I want it to read:

```
"Wear a jacket when you go outside."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple values to `print()` separated by commas.

`print(value_1, value_2, value_3)`

Comment: Ok but the first value I'm printing is dependent on the "if" and "else" statements, whereas the second value is separate and gets printed no matter what.

Do I need to write it twice (once in the "if" portion and once again in the "else" portion of the code)?

Comment: You can use it like this `print("Wear a jacket ", end=' ')` for both print in if else.